# Use X509TrustManager for SSL in android

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509trustmanager

> I simply update gradle and some version of the app and the app is rejected by Google. I am calling **SOAP services** using `ksop library`.

**Email by Google**

We rejected your app, with package name blah.blah.blah, for violating our **Malicious Behavior** or **User Data policy**. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains `security vulnerabilities` for users or allows the collection of user data without `proper disclosure`.

> Vulnerability - > TrustManager

I am using below way to allow all SSL

```
    @SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
    public static void allowAllSSL() {

        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        javax.net.ssl.SSLContext context = null;

        if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[]{new _FakeX509TrustManager()};
        }

        try {
            context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // Log.e("allowAllSSL", e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("InternetOp.allowAllSSL", e.toString());
        }
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
    }
```

whrere _FakeX509TrustManager

```
public static class _FakeX509TrustManager implements
            javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager {

        private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
            return (true);
        }

        public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
            return (true);
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return (_AcceptedIssuers);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Now I am using below method . As i am a new bee and have less idea of SSL. tell me whether i am using it correctly or not.

**MySSLSocketFactory .class**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    /**
     * Creates a new SSL Socket Factory with the given KeyStore.
     *
     * @param truststore A KeyStore to create the SSL Socket Factory in context of
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException    KeyManagementException
     * @throws KeyStoreException         KeyStoreException
     * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException UnrecoverableKeyException
     */
    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                try {
                    chain[0].checkValidity();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                }
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                try {
                    chain[0].checkValidity();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                }
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a KeyStore containing the Certificate
     *
     * @param cert InputStream of the Certificate
     * @return KeyStore
     */
    public static KeyStore getKeystoreOfCA(InputStream cert) {

        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        InputStream caInput = null;
        Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            caInput = new BufferedInputStream(cert);
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } catch (CertificateException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (caInput != null) {
                    caInput.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a Default KeyStore
     *
     * @return KeyStore
     */
    public static KeyStore getKeystore() {
        KeyStore trustStore = null;
        try {
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return trustStore;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a SSlSocketFactory which trusts all certificates
     *
     * @return SSLSocketFactory
     */
    public static SSLSocketFactory getFixedSocketFactory() {
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
        try {
            socketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(getKeystore());
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        }
        return socketFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a DefaultHttpClient which trusts a set of certificates specified by the KeyStore
     *
     * @param keyStore custom provided KeyStore instance
     * @return DefaultHttpClient
     */
    public static DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient(KeyStore keyStore) {

        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        Socket localSocket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        enableSecureProtocols(localSocket);
        return localSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        enableSecureProtocols(socket);
        return socket;
    }

    /**
     * Activate supported protocols on the socket.
     *
     * @param socket    The socket on which to activate secure protocols.
     */
    private void enableSecureProtocols(Socket socket) {
        // set all supported protocols
        SSLParameters params = sslContext.getSupportedSSLParameters();
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(params.getProtocols());
    }

    /**
     * Makes HttpsURLConnection trusts a set of certificates specified by the KeyStore
     */
    public void fixHttpsURLConnection() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

**_FakeX509TrustManager.class**

```
public static class _FakeX509TrustManager
        implements X509TrustManager {

    private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

    /**
     * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager.
     */
    public _FakeX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        super();
        TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        factory.init(keystore);
        TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustmanagers.length == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");
        }
        this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];
    }

    /**
     * @see X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[], String authType)
     */
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
        standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
    }

    /**
     * @see X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String authType)
     */
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
        if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
            certificates[0].checkValidity();
        } else {
            standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers()
     */
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
    }

}
```

Am I using correct SSL

Comment: "I am using below way to allow all SSL" -- that is your problem. Get rid of all of that. Use SSL properly, please.

Comment: You're wondering why they rejected an app that claims to support SSL but does not, and instead provides a `FakeX509TrustManager` that does not actually function? Really? And you have to ask us to explain it to you? Seriously?